# Recorded Macro Error: Method 'CreatePivotTable' of object 'PivotCache' failed

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded a macro for creating a pivot table on the existing sheet but am getting Error: Method 'CreatePivotTable' of object 'PivotCache' failed. Would really appreciate help with how to get rid of this error! Thanks.

```
Sub MakePivot()

ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-45
Columns("A:Y").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= 
    "New!R1C1:R1048576C25", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). 
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("____")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("______"), "Count of ______", xlCount
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Value "), "Count of Value ", xlCount
ExecuteExcel4Macro _
    "PIVOT.FIELD.PROPERTIES(""PivotTable1"",""Count of ______"",,,2)"
ExecuteExcel4Macro _
    "PIVOT.FIELD.PROPERTIES(""PivotTable1"",""Count of Value "",,,2)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "New!R1C1:R1048576C25", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

You deleted two of the underscores at the end of the line. These are required for Excel to know that the line of code continues down to the next line.

Comment: I am still getting the exact same error after changing that. Do you have any other suggestions of changes I could make? Thanks!

Comment: I am not able to duplicate your error. Is your sheet still called "New"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug of Excel Application.
I've solved this problem like this.

This example use already existing WorkbookConnection.

```
 'Get WorkbookConnection object
 Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
 Set conn =  ActiveWorkbook.Connections("MyConnectionName")
 
 'Declare temp variables
 Dim connStr As String
 Dim sqlStr As String
 
 'Store connection string and command text in variables depends on connection type
 If conn.Type = xlConnectionTypeODBC Then
   connStr = conn.ODBCConnection.Connection
   sqlStr = conn.ODBCConnection.CommandText
 End If
  
 If conn.Type = xlConnectionTypeOLEDB Then
   connStr = conn.OLEDBConnection.Connection
   sqlStr = conn.OLEDBConnection.CommandText
 End If
 
 'Create PivotCache
 Dim pcache As pivotCache
 Set pcache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlExternal, conn)
 
 'Then we need to get recordset to create pivot table
 Dim adodb_conn As Object
 Dim rs As Object
 Set adodb_conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
 adodb_conn.Open connStr
 rs.Open sqlStr, adodb_conn
 
 Set pcache.Recordset = rs
 'When CreatePivotTable method called the linked WorkbookConnection is losing connection string and command text
 Set pvt = pcache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Sheets("MySheetName").Cells(1, 1), TableName:="MyPivotTableName")
        
 rs.Close
 adodb_conn.Close
 
 'Restore CommandText and connection string
 pcache.CommandText = sqlStr
 pcache.Connection = connStr
 
 ' Now you have PivotTable that linked with yours WorkbookConnection
```